By acquiring loot in a game and splitting the sale value between x, what is the impact on profit when doing the split with a non participant?
To start, I want to contextualize this question. In the MMO OldSchool Runescape there is a raid called the Theater of Blood. In it a group of 4 or 5 players (technically could be any number of players from 1 to 5 but I want to keep this at 4 or 5) go through this raid and get loot at the end.
Sometimes at the end of this raid, there exists a chance to obtain a unique kind of loot roll called a "Purple". This loot is highly sought after and extremely valuable. Traditionally, it is agreed upon that whoever rolls this unique loot piece sells the loot piece immediately and splits the sale value across the entire party. For example if something sells for 1 Billion, each member of a 4 man party would get 250 Million.
There exists a particular kind of player account, called an "Ironman" that cannot trade with other players and thus cannot sell the loot he rolls or get paid his fair share of the split if the other 3 roll it.
So the question in essence becomes, what would be the impact on the profit of the remaining members of the party if they introduced an "Ironman" player to their party? The loot agreement would become something akin to:

If the Ironman rolls the Purple unique loot, he keeps it all to himself. If the rest of the party rolls that loot they divide the loot only between themselves.

Here are some numbers that we can assume:

$\ x = numberOfPlayers $ limited between let's say 4 and 5.

There exists an 11% chance to roll a "Purple" item at the end of the raid. The game then picks a player with equal chance to obtain the item for themselves (it is based on performance but let's assume equal performance). So $\ \frac1x $ chance someone gets it.

The - name | quantity | chance | price - of getting any one item are shown in the image below but they are chances calculated before the 11% purple roll, so while you are expected to get the first item 1 in 21 times that means 1 in every 21 of ANY type of loot roll, not just the unique, but only the unique rolls are split. In other words, the chances of getting any of those items are a lot higher if you have already rolled the Purple (but I'm afraid I don't know how to calculate how much higher).


https://imgur.com/a/zMsx8xZ

On average a group is expected to get a "Scythe of Vitur" every 172 raids, and thus there is a $\ \frac1{172} *\frac1x $ any one player gets it in any given raid and $\ \frac1{172} *\frac{x-1}x $ chance that the group gets to split the 1.5 Billion by $\ x-1 $ players if there is one "Ironman" in the party.

The group can on average complete 2 raids per hour.


So given these odds and the value of each item, I'd like to somehow figure out the impact of adding a non participant a.k.a an "Ironman" to this group versus having a group full group.
For example, here is the common scenario:

Given 500 raids which would take 250 hours, how much money per hour would each member of the group make if they divided the loot equally?

My idea of this would be to divide the number of raids by the average amount of raids per item. So for example in 500 raids I would get about 24 "Avernic Defender Hilt". Do the same for all items add up the price and divide by x.
And here is the hypothetical "Ironman" scenario:

Given 500 raids which would take 250 hours, how much money per hour would each non ironman member of the group make if they divided their drops between themselves? Effectively how much does replacing a normal member by an Ironman affect the non-ironman's profit?

I'm unsure how to calculate the difference 1 person makes in this scenario. I'm also not certain I am correct in my previous assessment either.
Here is a wiki page that may be helpful:
https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Monumental_chest

Without Ironman, you always get $\frac1n$ of the loot. With one Ironman, you get $\frac1{n-1}$ of the loot but only $\frac{n-1}n$ of the time. So the expected value of the loot you get is the same.
You get the same expectation if you have any number $k<n$ of "Ironmen" in the game.

I have since written a python script to simulate the experiment and it also matches up with what you're describing. Thanks!
